# Ruby using step method to return large numbers with delimiter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
(2500..75000).step(2500).to_a
 #=> [2500, 5000, 7500, 10000, 12500, 15000, 17500, 20000, 22500, 25000, 27500, 30000, 32500, 35000, 37500, 40000, 42500, 45000, 47500, 50000, 52500, 55000, 57500, 60000, 62500, 65000, 67500, 70000, 72500, 75000]
```

How do I get the output to be: `[ '2,500', '5,000', '7,500', '10,000', '12,500', ... ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Rails, you can use the [`number_with_delimiter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_delimiter) helper:

```
(1..30).map { |i| number_with_delimiter(2500*i) }
```

Comment: The comma is the default delimiter, so you can remove the `:delimiter` option.

Comment: Also if the numbers are meaningful, you lose the documentation value if you factor out the 2500. I'd probably leave the original numbers and the `step`.

Comment: @MarkThomas Yes, I guess the question is what do you want to be more obvious: The length of the array (30 as above) or the min/max values using step. Hard to tell from the question out of context, so I just went with the former.

Comment: @Matt I found that number_with_delimiter method, but for some reason I can't get it to work. What are the dependencies? I tried to require 'rails' in irb (true) but `(1..30).map { |i| number_with_delimiter(2500*i) }` returns `#=> undefined method number_with_delimiter' for main:Object`

Comment: @feed_me_code From the [rails console](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html), run `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` then the above code. If you're running this from within a `View` then it should just work.

Comment: @Matt, Gotcha thanks. A heck of lot more code for the same output however. I can see the use if I needed to numbers greater than 5 digits. +1

Answer (score 1):

In pure Ruby

```
(1..30).map { |i| (2500*i).to_s.reverse.gsub(%r{([0-9]{3}(?=([0-9])))}, "\\1,").reverse }
```

To be honest, the regex used above was not created by me. And also it is not very readable.

This is my real functional solution in pure Ruby (if case you are not in Rails or you do not want to use the helper number_with_delimiter):

```
(1..30).map { |i| (2500*i).to_s.reverse.split("").reduce{|acc, n| "#{n}#{',' if acc.delete(',').length%3==0}#{acc}" } }
```

Extracting it into a method

```
def number_with_delimiter(number, delimiter = ',')
  number.to_s.reverse.split("").reduce do |acc, n| 
    if acc.delete(delimiter).length % 3 == 0  
      "#{n}#{delimiter}#{acc}"
    else
      "#{n}#{acc}"
    end
  end
end
```

Works for any number, for example:

```
> (1..15).map { |i| number_with_delimiter(75000*i) }
 => ["75,000", "150,000", "225,000", "300,000", "375,000", "450,000", "525,000",
     "600,000", "675,000", "750,000", "825,000", "900,000", "975,000", 
     "1,050,000", "1,125,000"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is:

```
('2,500'..'75,000').step(2500).to_a
```

Comment: Fyi this won't generalize to numbers with additional commas. For example `('999,000'..'1,001,000').step(1000).to_a == []` due to how `succ` works with `step` - it is not intelligent about commas. (btw I did not downvote)

Comment: @Matt yeah I realized that but for my use case, it works fine. I'm just dynamically building a drop down select menu. Down vote was not warranted (whoever did it).

Comment: I downvoted this. This answer is not a general purpose solution to the question, and your simplifying assumption that it works for "your use case" was not specified in the question.